# plotly pie subplots side by side with two dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, plotly

I have two tables, and I am trying to create subplots side by side, the first figure works fine but the second figure is same in each row.

ax

```
          Item                                   Nutrients      value

0 Bacon & Cheese Whopper® Sandwich             Fat Calories     460.0
1 Bacon & Cheese Whopper® Sandwich             Total Carb (g)   50.0
2 Bacon & Cheese Whopper® Sandwich             Protein (g)      35.0
3 Bacon Cheeseburger                           Fat Calories     140.0
4 Bacon Cheeseburger                           Total Carb (g)   27.0
5 Bacon Cheeseburger                           Protein (g)      17.0
```

daily_calories_intake

```
          Item                               Gender_dv            value

0 Bacon & Cheese Whopper® Sandwich           dv_calories_men      48.8
1 Bacon & Cheese Whopper® Sandwich           dv_calories_women    47.7
2 Bacon Cheeseburger                         dv_calories_men      46.0
3 Bacon Cheeseburger                         dv_calories_women    45.2
```

I have tried to make pie plots side by side, this is my code:

```
lst = list(ax.groupby('Item'))
gen = list(daily_calories_intake.groupby('Item'))

rows = 22
cols = 2

subplot_titles = [l[0] for l in lst]
specs = [[{'type':'domain'},{'type':'domain'}]]*rows

fig = make_subplots(
        rows=rows,
        cols=cols,
        subplot_titles=subplot_titles,
        specs=specs)

for i, l in enumerate(lst):
    for j,k in enumerate(gen):
        d = l[1]
        m = k[1]
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Pie(labels = d['Nutritients'],
                   values = d['value']),row = i+1,col=1)
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Pie(labels = m['Gender_dv'],
                   values = m['value']),row = i+1,col=2)


fig.update_layout(autosize=True,height=8000, showlegend=True, margin= 
    {"l":0,"r":0,"t":100,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

I can't figure out how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nested loop doesn't work here because you're overwriting the graph. Creating a single loop with `zip` would work:

```
for i, (l,k) in enumerate(zip(lst, gen)):
    d = l[1]
    m = k[1]
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Pie(labels = d['Nutrients'],
              values = d['value']),row = i+1,col=1)
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Pie(labels = m['Gender_dv'],
               values = m['value']),row = i+1,col=2)
```

Edit: your titles seem off, transpose the plots to get the charts under the corresponding titles:

```
for i, (l,k) in enumerate(zip(lst, gen)):
    d = l[1]
    m = k[1]
    fig.add_trace(go.Pie(labels=d['Nutrients'], values=d['value']), row=1, col=i+1)
    fig.add_trace(go.Pie(labels=m['Gender_dv'], values=m['value']), row=2, col=i+1)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You're welcome! BTW I think the titles are off, you should transpose the plots: `row=1,col=i+1` and `row=2,col=i+1` respectively.

Comment: this code is still giving the same result as my code. the second figure is same in all rows

Comment: No it isn't. The men/women graphs are (slightly) different in my answer. The changes in my comment (`row=1,col=i+1` and `row=2,col=i+1`) are just meant to reorder the graphs in columns instead of rows so that the titles (burger names) are set on top of the corresponding pies.

Comment: Have you plotted all options? I edited my answer

Comment: fig = make_subplots(
        rows=rows,
        cols=cols,
        subplot_titles=('Calories','Gender Daily Intake'),
        specs=specs)

for i, (l,k) in enumerate(zip(lst, gen)):
        d = l[1]
        m = k[1]
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Pie(labels = d['Nutrients'],
                   values = d['value'], title=l[0],
                   hole=.4),row = i+1,col=1)
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Pie(labels = m['Gender_dv'],
                   values = m['value'], title=k[0],
                   hole=.4),row = i+1,col=2)

Comment: yes you can specify a title for each graph with `title=k[0]` and `title=l[0]` then you don't need `subplot_titles=subplot_titles,`

Comment: this is the latest code that i have tried all the titles are in correct position with this code but same problem the second graphs are all same

Comment: then you are probably using different data than in your question... see my screenshot

Comment: it's the same dataset but it has  about 77 rows. thank you soo much for your help and really appreciate you for being patient with me.

Comment: If you're still having troubles, I suggest you create a new question with a minimal example including all the necessary code to reproduce the problem (imports, dataframe constructors...) then you'll get a solution in no time!